# Rx distinctUntilChanged allow repetition after configurable time between events

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

Let's consider for a moment the following code

```
Rx.Observable.merge(
  Rx.Observable.just(1),
  Rx.Observable.just(1).delay(1000)
).distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

We expect that `1` is logged just once. However what if we wanted to allow repetition of a value if its last emission was a configurable amount of time ago? I mean to **get both events logged**.

For example it would be cool to have something like the following

```
Rx.Observable.merge(
  Rx.Observable.just(1),
  Rx.Observable.just(1).delay(1000)
).distinctUntilChanged(1000)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

In which `distinctUntilChanged()` accepts some sort of timeout to allow repetition on the next element. However such a thing does not exist and I was wondering if anybody knows an elegant way to achieve this by using high level operators without messing with a filter that would require handling state

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding I am pretty sure this could be accomplished in a relatively straight-forward manner with `windowTime`:

```
Observable
  .merge(
   Observable.of(1),
   Observable.of(1).delay(250), // Ignored
   Observable.of(1).delay(700), // Ignored
   Observable.of(1).delay(2000),
   Observable.of(1).delay(2200), //Ignored
   Observable.of(2).delay(2300)
  )
  // Converts the stream into a stream of streams each 1000 milliseconds long
  .windowTime(1000)
  // Flatten each of the streams and emit only the latest (there should only be one active 
  // at a time anyway
  // We apply the distinctUntilChanged to the windows before flattening
  .switchMap(source => source.distinctUntilChanged())  
  .timeInterval()
  .subscribe(
    value => console.log(value),
    error => console.log('error: ' + error),
    () => console.log('complete')
  );
```

See the example [here](https://jsbin.com/tulojogudi/edit?js,console) (borrowed @martin's example inputs)

Comment: Awesome, a very clever solution to the problem - should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Didn't know about the window operator. I had implemented something like this in a convoluted way but this really simplifies it. Thanks!

Although I noticed this can emit repeated elements if they happen near a window boundary (e.g. 990ms and 1010ms). I changed it to make the boundary timeout relative to the last distinct item:
`obs.window(obs.distinctUntilChanged().switchMap(s=>Observable.timer(1000)))`. See the modified [example](https://jsbin.com/soyovumeja/edit?js,console).

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting use-case. I wonder whether there's an easier solution than mine (note that I'm using RxJS 5):

```
let timedDistinctUntil = Observable.defer(() => {
    let innerObs = null;
    let innerSubject = null;
    let delaySub = null;

    function tearDown() {
        delaySub.unsubscribe();
        innerSubject.complete();
    }

    return Observable
        .merge(
            Observable.of(1),
            Observable.of(1).delay(250),  // ignored
            Observable.of(1).delay(700),  // ignored
            Observable.of(1).delay(2000),
            Observable.of(1).delay(2200), // ignored
            Observable.of(2).delay(2300)
        )
        .do(undefined, undefined, () => tearDown())
        .map(value => {
            if (innerObs) {
                innerSubject.next(value);
                return null;
            }

            innerSubject = new BehaviorSubject(value);

            delaySub = Observable.of(null).delay(1000).subscribe(() => {
                innerObs = null;
            });

            innerObs = innerSubject.distinctUntilChanged();
            return innerObs;
        })
        // filter out all skipped Observable emissions
        .filter(observable => observable)
        .switch();
});

timedDistinctUntil
    .timestamp()
    .subscribe(
        value => console.log(value),
        error => console.log('error: ' + error),
        () => console.log('complete')
    );
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/sivuxo/5/edit?js,console

The entire logic is wrapped into `Observable.defer()` static method because it requires some additional variables.

A couple points how this all works:

1. The `merge()` is the source of items.
2. I use `do()` to properly catch when the source completes so I can shutdown the internal timer and send proper complete notification.
3. The `map()` operator is where the most interesting things happen. I reemit the value that it received and then return `null` if there's already a valid Observable (it was created less then 1000ms ago = `innerObs != null`). Then I eventually create a new Subject where I'm going to reemit all items and return this `BehaviorSubject` chained with `.distinctUntilChanged()`. At the end I schedule 1s delay to set `innerObs = null` which means then when another value arrives it'll return a new Observable with new `.distinctUntilChanged()`.
4. Then `filter()` will let me ignore all `null` values returned. This means it won't emit a new Observable more than once a second.
5. Now I need to work with so called Higher-order Observables (Observables emitting Observables. For this reason I use `switch()` operator that always subscribes only to the newest Observable emitted by the source. In our case we emit Observables only max. once a second (thanks to the `filter()` used above) and this inner itself Observable can emit as many values it wants and all of them are going to be passed through `distinctUntilChanged()` so duplicates are ignored.

The output for this demo will look like the following output:

```
Timestamp { value: 1, timestamp: 1484670434528 }
Timestamp { value: 1, timestamp: 1484670436475 }
Timestamp { value: 2, timestamp: 1484670436577 }
complete
```

As you can see the value `1` is emitted twice with cca 2s delay. However value `2` passed without any problem after 100ms thanks to `distinctUntilChanged()`.

I know this isn't simple but I hope it makes sense to you :)

Comment: Nice answer - I liked this usecase as well - might be even worth to create a custom operator - I could imagine more people are going to have this issue.